# Unexpected websocket buffer data w/ masked fragmented messages: As data grows, server starts receiving what looks random data, not matching frame spec

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to implement a websocket server from scratch in NodeJS following the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1), below is my NodeJS code (still has some console-logs for testing) that can be run and tested currently:

```
//B"H
var http = require("http")
var crypto = require("crypto")

var awdawneem = [

];

var server  = http.createServer(function(
    request,
    response
) {
    awdawneem.forEach(a => {
        koysayv("Happy hey teves! " + Date.now(), a)
    })
    response.end("Boruch Hashem!")
}).listen(8081, () => {
    server.on("upgrade", (request, socket) => {
        var ki = request.headers[
            "sec-websocket-key"
        ]

        if(!ki) {
            return;
        }

        awdawneem.push(socket);

        var added = ki + 
            "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
        
        var base64string = crypto
        .createHash("sha1")
        .update(
            added
        ).digest("base64")

        var responseHeaders = [
            "HTTP/1.1 101 Awtsmoos",
            "upgrade: websocket",
            "connection: upgrade",
            "sec-websocket-accept: "
                + base64string
        ]

        socket.write(
            responseHeaders.join(
                "\r\n"
            ) + "\r\n\r\n"
        )

        
        koysayv("Shalom", socket)
        shoymayuh(socket, payloads => {
            console.log("Got pay!",payloads)
        })
    })
})

function koysayv(str,socket) {
    var encoded = encodeDayuh(str)
    if(encoded) {
        try {
            socket.write(encoded)
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("something",e)
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("Nothing")
    }
}

function shoymayuh/*listen*/(socket,cb) {
    var payloads = [];
    var isInMiddleOfGetting = false;
    var currentFrameIndex = 0;
    var isBeginning = false;

    var callback = typeof(cb) == "function"
        ? cb : (() => {})
    socket.on("data", buff => {
        if(!buff || buff.length < 1) {
            payloads = [];
            return callback({
                error: "No length!",
                buff
            })
        }
        var FIN = (
            buff[0] >> 7 
            & 1
        )
        

        var opcode = (
            buff[0] &
            0b00001111
        )

        if(!FIN) {
            isInMiddleOfGetting = true;
            currentFrameIndex = payloads.length;
            if(opcode) {
                isBeginning = true;
            } else {
                isBeginning = false;
            }
        }

        var isMasked = (
            buff[1] >> 7 & 1
        )

        if(!isMasked) {
            return callback({
                error: "Not masked",
                isMasked,buff
            })
        }

        var lengthCode = (
            buff[1] &
            0b01111111
        )

        var whereToReadMask = 2/*3rd byte*/
        var lengthOfPayload;
        if(lengthCode < 126) {
            lengthOfPayload = lengthCode;
        } else if(lengthCode < Math.pow(2,16)) {
            lengthOfPayload = buff.readUInt16BE(2)
            whereToReadMask = 4
        } else if(lengthCode < Math.pow(2,64)) {
            lengthOfPayload = buff.readBigUInt64BE(2)
            whereToReadMask = 10
        } else {
            return callback("Too big")
        }

        var maskData = buff.slice(
            whereToReadMask,
            whereToReadMask + 4
        );
        var whereToReadPayload = whereToReadMask + 4

        
        if(
            whereToReadPayload + 
            lengthOfPayload > buff.length 
        ) {
            return callback({
                error: "Length problem",
                info: {
                    lengthOfPayload,
                    maskedPayload,
                    maskData,
                    isMasked,
                    FIN,
                    isMasked,
                    opcode
                }
            })
        }

        var maskedPayload = buff.slice(
            whereToReadPayload,
            whereToReadPayload + 
            lengthOfPayload
        )

        

        var unmaskedPayload = Buffer.alloc(maskedPayload.length)
        var i;
        var maskIndex;
        for(
            i = 0;
            i < maskedPayload.length;
            i++
        ) {
            maskIndex = maskData[i % 4]
            unmaskedPayload[i] = 
            maskedPayload[i] ^ maskIndex
        }

        console.log(
            "Pushing payload: ",
            unmaskedPayload,
            unmaskedPayload.length,{
                FIN,
                opcode,
                whereToReadPayload,
                whereToReadMask,
                buffLength:buff.length,
                maskData,
                isMasked,
                buff
            }
        )
        payloads.push(unmaskedPayload)

        if(FIN) {
            callback({
                success: {
                    strings: payloads.map(q=>q.toString()),
                    original: payloads
                },
                info: {
                    FIN,
                    opcode,
                    whereToReadMask,
                    whereToReadPayload,
                    maskData,
                    isMasked,
                    lengthOfPayload,
                    maskedLength:maskedPayload.length,
                    bufferLength: buff.length,
                    lengthOfAllPayloads:payloads.length

                }
            })
            payloads = [];
        }
    })
}

function encodeDayuh(mightBeBuffer) {
    if(!mightBeBuffer) return;

    var str = mightBeBuffer.toString();

    var lengthOfPayload = Buffer.byteLength(str)
    var howManyBytesToAdd;
    if(lengthOfPayload < 126) {
        howManyBytesToAdd = 0
    } else if(lengthOfPayload < Math.pow(2,16)) {
        howManyBytesToAdd = 2
    } else if(lengthOfPayload < Math.pow(2,64)) {
        howManyBytesToAdd = 8
    } else return console.log("TOO BIG");

    var bufferToSend = Buffer.alloc(
        2 
        + howManyBytesToAdd
        + lengthOfPayload
    );

    var offset = 0;
    bufferToSend.writeUInt8(
        0b10000001,
        offset
    )

    offset = 1;
    if(lengthOfPayload < 126) {
        bufferToSend.writeUInt8(
            lengthOfPayload,
            offset
        )
        offset = 2
    } else if(lengthOfPayload < Math.pow(2, 16)) {
        bufferToSend.writeUInt8(
            0b01111110/*126*/,
            offset
        )
        offset = 2;
        bufferToSend.writeUInt16BE(
            lengthOfPayload,
            offset
        )

        
        offset = 4;
    } else if(lengthOfPayload < Math.pow(2, 64)) {
        bufferToSend.writeUInt8(
            0b01111111,
            offset
        )

        offset = 2;
        bufferToSend.writeBigUInt64BE(
            lengthOfPayload,
            offset
        )
        offset = 10
    }

    bufferToSend.write(
        str,
        offset
    )
    

    return bufferToSend;

}
```

Try connecting to it with any client on localhost [haven't tested if it changes when on a remote server]. It should work up until a certain amount, but as the data gets bigger (still less than 2 to the power of 64), it starts receiving what appears to be random data which doesn't match the frame specification.

For example if I run the following:

```
var something = new WebSocket(
    "ws://localhost:8081"
)

something.onopen = () => {
    console.log("opened")
    something.send("BH".repeat(1000000))
}

something.onmessage = e=>{
    console.log(e.data)
}
"BH".repeat(1000000).length < Math.pow(2,64);
```

You can see that the length of the message is still less than 2^64, so it should work. On the server side the first frame that's sent looks normal, with the FIN bit set to 0 indicating a continuation, but then the next "frame" doesn't appear to have the same format as the first one, even [some of] the first 3 "reserved" bits are sometimes taken, and the "masking" bit isn't always set to 0, here's an example of some of the output [cut off after a little bit]:

```
Pushing payload:  <Buffer > 0 {
  FIN: 0,
  opcode: 1,
  whereToReadPayload: 8,
  whereToReadMask: 4,
  buffLength: 32768,
  maskData: <Buffer 00 00 00 01>,
  isMasked: 1,
  buff: <Buffer 01 ff 00 00 00 00 00 01 ff b8 32 85 76 d3 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b ... 32718 more bytes>
}
Pushing payload:  <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00> 27 {
  FIN: 0,
  opcode: 4,
  whereToReadPayload: 6,
  whereToReadMask: 2,
  buffLength: 65536,
  maskData: <Buffer 70 cd 34 9b>,
  isMasked: 1,
  buff: <Buffer 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b ... 65486 more bytes>
}
Pushing payload:  <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00> 27 {
  FIN: 0,
  opcode: 4,
  whereToReadPayload: 6,
  whereToReadMask: 2,
  buffLength: 65536,
  maskData: <Buffer 70 cd 34 9b>,
  isMasked: 1,
  buff: <Buffer 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b 70 cd 34 9b ... 65486 more bytes>
}
Got pay! {
  error: 'Not masked',
  isMasked: 0,
  buff: <Buffer 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a ... 65486 more bytes>
}
Got pay! {
  error: 'Not masked',
  isMasked: 0,
  buff: <Buffer 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a 96 98 33 1a ... 65486 more bytes>
}
```

So a lot of the output is simply unpredictable, some of the opcodes aren't even value, most of it isn't even masked etc.

There's no example in the RFC for *masked* fragmented messages, here at the examples given:

```
5.7.  Examples

   o  A single-frame unmasked text message

      *  0x81 0x05 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f (contains "Hello")

   o  A single-frame masked text message

      *  0x81 0x85 0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d 0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58
         (contains "Hello")

   o  A fragmented unmasked text message

      *  0x01 0x03 0x48 0x65 0x6c (contains "Hel")

      *  0x80 0x02 0x6c 0x6f (contains "lo")







Fette & Melnikov             Standards Track                   [Page 38]

RFC 6455                 The WebSocket Protocol            December 2011


   o  Unmasked Ping request and masked Ping response

      *  0x89 0x05 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f (contains a body of "Hello",
         but the contents of the body are arbitrary)

      *  0x8a 0x85 0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d 0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58
         (contains a body of "Hello", matching the body of the ping)

   o  256 bytes binary message in a single unmasked frame

      *  0x82 0x7E 0x0100 [256 bytes of binary data]

   o  64KiB binary message in a single unmasked frame

      *  0x82 0x7F 0x0000000000010000 [65536 bytes of binary data]
```

Maybe it's a problem with reading the order of the frames?

Comment: I think the question is, does the web browser automatically mask fragmented messages? Or maybe each subsequent message should be decoded with the masking key from the first message?

Comment: I also assume you mean the masking bit isn't always set to 1, since the browser always masks

Comment: You only check if `buff` is at least one byte, then blindly assume you got the whole frame.

Comment: @gre_gor I've been following this question having a similar issue, how else should he check if the whole frame was gotten, what else could have been gotten?

Comment: You are also reading the payload length wrong.

Comment: @gre_gor that's right, it should be if it's 126 then read the next 2 bytes, if it's 127 then read next 8..

Comment: @gre_gor I' was thinking about this, and while it's true, but it doesn't explain why subsequent frames start with the FIN as 1 even though it all should be part of one big fragmentation, in addition to the some frames having reserved bits taken (which should be grounds for closing the connection), as well as the mask bit set to 0, as all of that was before reading the length. Maybe there's a ping request injected into it or something? If so the opcode also doesn't always match. Also he's reading them in BE, should the lengths etc be read instead in LE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are falsely assuming that the whole frame will be in your `buff` chunk. You need to concatenate those chunks into a single buffer and try to parse out the frame, if you have enough data in the buffer.

You are also reading the payload length wrong. You are supposed to check `lengthCode` for value of 126 and 127, not if they are smaller than 2<sup>16</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup>. A 7 bit integer won't even reach 2<sup>7</sup>.

Whey you properly read the frame you will notice that the payload length (131000) of the first frame exceeds the length of the `buff` chunk (32768).

Also notice that your "second frame" just repeats the same 4 bytes like your payload in the first, which indicates it's still just payload data.

I fixed your code and added some debugging output put to make it clear when a chunk is received and when is the frame actually parsed.

```js
const OPCODE = {
    CONTUNIATION: 0,
    TEXT: 1,
    BINARY: 2,
    CLOSE: 8,
    PING: 9,
    PONG: 10,
};

function shoymayuh(socket, callback) {
    let fragmented_message_opcode;
    let fragmented_message_payload;
    let buff = Buffer.alloc(0);
    let frame_count = 0;
    let chunk_count = 0;

    socket.on("data", chunk => {
        if(!chunk || chunk.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        // add chunk to the buffer
        buff = Buffer.concat([buff, chunk]);
        console.log(`got chunk #${++chunk_count} of size: ${chunk.length} bytes (buffer: ${buff.length} bytes)`);
        
        // there might be multiple frames in the buffer, try to parse from the buffer until we can't anymore
        for (;;) {
            // if not enough data to read the first 2 bytes of the header, skip and wait for more
            if (buff.length < 2) {
                return;
            }
            const FIN = Boolean(buff[0] & 0b10000000);
            
            let opcode = buff[0] & 0b00001111;

            const isMasked = Boolean(buff[1] & 0b10000000);

            const lengthCode = buff[1] & 0b01111111;

            // read the payload length
            let offset = 2;
            let lengthOfPayload;
            if(lengthCode <= 125) {
                lengthOfPayload = lengthCode;
            } else if(lengthCode == 126) {
                // if not enough data to read the payload length, skip and wait for more
                if (buff.length < offset + 2) {
                    return;
                }
                lengthOfPayload = buff.readUInt16BE(offset);
                offset += 2
            } else if(lengthCode == 127) {
                // if not enough data to read the payload length, skip and wait for more
                if (buff.length < offset + 8) {
                    return;
                }
                // readBigUInt64BE returns a BigInt, convert it to Number
                lengthOfPayload = Number(buff.readBigUInt64BE(offset));
                offset += 8
            }

            // read the mask if masked
            let maskData;
            if (isMasked) {
                // if not enough data to read the mask, skip and wait for more
                if (buff.length < offset + 4) {
                    return;
                }
                maskData = buff.slice(offset, offset + 4);
                offset += 4;
            }

            // if not enough data to read the payload, skip and wait for more
            if(offset + lengthOfPayload > buff.length) {
                return;
            }

            // extract the payload
            let payload = buff.slice(offset, offset + lengthOfPayload);

            // unmask the payload if masked
            if (isMasked) {
                payload = payload.map((b, i) => b ^ maskData[i%4]);
            }

            // remove the parsed frame from the buffer
            buff = buff.slice(offset + lengthOfPayload);

            // concatanate payload if fragmented message
            if (opcode == OPCODE.CONTUNIATION) {
                fragmented_message_payload = Buffer.concat([fragmented_message_payload, payload]);
            }

            console.log("parsed frame", "#"+(++frame_count), {
                FIN,
                opcode,
                isMasked,
                lengthCode,
                lengthOfPayload,
                maskData,
                payload,
            });
            console.log(buff.length, "bytes left in buffer")

            if(FIN) {
                if (opcode == OPCODE.CONTUNIATION) {
                    opcode = fragmented_message_opcode;
                    payload = fragmented_message_payload;
                }

                if (opcode == OPCODE.PING) {
                    callback({
                        ping: payload,
                    });
                }
                else if (opcode == OPCODE.PONG) {
                    callback({
                        pong: payload,
                    });
                }
                else if (opcode == OPCODE.CLOSE) {
                    let code = 1005;
                    if (payload.length >= 2) {
                        code = payload.readUInt16BE();
                        payload = payload.slice(2);
                    }
                    callback({
                        close: code,
                        payload: payload,
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // if it was a text frame, convert it to string
                    if (opcode == OPCODE.TEXT) {
                        payload = payload.toString("utf8");
                    }
                    callback({
                        message: payload,
                    });
                }
                fragmented_message_opcode = undefined;
                fragmented_message_payload = undefined;
            }
            else {
                if (opcode == OPCODE.TEXT || opcode == OPCODE.BINARY) {
                    fragmented_message_opcode = opcode;
                    fragmented_message_payload = payload;
                }
                else if (opcode != OPCODE.CONTUNIATION) {
                    throw new Exception("Fragmented control frame");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. that length reading was a blunder, not sure what I was thinking. Regarding the other frames, I must have thought that every frame at least has a FIN bit with the 3 reserved empty bits and the opcode, and a custom length for that section [with a 0 FIN bit indicating it's a piece in the fragmented chunk], I must have understood the RFC wrong, the examples they showed showed a FIN bit set in a [non-masked] fragment piece, I guess I just assumed that each "fragment piece" must be a separate buffer. I also didn't realize that there can be multiple frames in one buffer. where

Comment: -is it written more in the RFC article, or elsewhere, when / how it's decided that a frame should end within a buffer, or if there is a way to "control" how many frames are in a buffer or how manner buffers are taken up by a frame, for testing?

Comment: Each frame does have FIN, reserved bits, opcode and length, but each chunk doesn't, since it might be just a continuation of the frame.

Comment: And the underlying protocol of WebSockets is TCP, which is a stream based protocol, which has no concept of messages/frames. It doesn't know when your frame starts/stops, it just sends you a stream of bytes in chunks of random lengths. It's not mentioned in RFC, because it's assumed that you are already familiar with TCP.

Comment: Oh ok got it, that was the part I missed {I guess I equated frames and chunks}, thanks